# Call external JavaScript function from React and pass and function as parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried calling an external javascript method from a React component. The JavaScript method interface is:

```
function executeAction(id, action,onDone) where onDone is a funcion to execute at the end of the action.
```

I can call this way

```
window["executeWidgetActionWithCallBack"]("id1","action1",reactFunction);
```

But I don't know how to define `reactFunction` in my React component. Any clues?

Comment: Could you show your component?

Comment: `executeAction` name is different from `executeWidgetActionWithCallBack` which you're calling:

Comment: yes, it's another example only

Comment: the component is only a text to the user, the goal is to update some Text with the callback function reactFunction.